# How to fix parent element width to one of its child?

Tags: html, css

Can I fix width of `div.main` to be the same as `table.tbl2`? In the example below, I need `inline4` to be on the second line, and width of `div.main` equal to width of `table.tbl2`.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.tbl1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl2 td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.inline-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">

    <table class="tbl1">
      <tr>
        <td>text text text text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="tbl2">
      <tr>
        <td>text 1</td>
        <td>text 2</td>
        <td>text 3</td>
        <td>text 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="inline-div">inline1</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline2</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline3</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline4</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you use javascript?

Comment: can we change the html ?

Comment: @JK I can write javascript solution by myself, I am curios if there is css-only solution.

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, we can change html, I just need to expand `tbl2` dynamically, and add new inline-div's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to make the elements out of the flow so they won't affect the width. This is not a generic solution as you need to adjust few things depending on each situation.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom:0;
  position:relative;
}

.tbl1 {
  width: 100%;
}

.tbl2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.tbl2 td {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.bottom {
  position:absolute;
  right:-1px;
  left:-1px;
  top:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  border-top:none;
}

.inline-div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">

    <table class="tbl1">
      <tr>
        <td>text text text text</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table class="tbl2">
      <tr>
        <td>text 1</td>
        <td>text 2</td>
        <td>text 3</td>
        <td>text 4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="bottom">
    <div class="inline-div">inline1</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline2</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline3</div>
    <div class="inline-div">inline4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see you are "cheating" with borders, I am interesting, if this will not break existing layout, since `inline-div`'s are not part of `div.main`. For example, `div.container` has height only 2 tables, and not including `div.bottom`

Comment: @Zergatul as i said, it's not generic :) but at least you get the trick i used ;) after that you can adjust things to make it working within a more complex layout, you may for example add big magin-bottom to main that will contain these element and avoid any overlapping